# Select and organize same columns from different tables

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a MySQL database with multiple tables and those tables contain multiple columns that are equal, and I want to push that data into a google spreadsheet.

For example:

`table1` contains `id`, `name`, `page`, and a couple of columns specific for that table.

`table2` contains `id`, `name`, `page`, and a couple of different columns

`table3` also has `id`, `name`, `page`, and more unique columns, etc.

This is my code:

```
function readFromTable() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheetDetails = ss.getSheetByName('Details');
  var sheetData = ss.getSheetByName('Clients');

  var host = sheetDetails.getRange("B1").getValue();
  var databaseName = sheetDetails.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var userName = sheetDetails.getRange("B3").getValue();
  var password = sheetDetails.getRange("B4").getValue();
  var port = sheetDetails.getRange("B5").getValue();

  var url = 'jdbc:mysql://'+host+':'+port+'/'+databaseName;
  Logger.log(url);
  Logger.log(userName);
  Logger.log(password);
  var sql = 'SELECT id, name, page FROM table1 UNION SELECT id, name, page FROM table2 UNION SELECT id, name, page FROM table3';
try{
  var connection = Jdbc.getConnection(url, userName, password);

  var results = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
  var metaData = results.getMetaData();
  var columns = metaData.getColumnCount();

// Retrieve metaData to a 2D array
   var values = [];
   var value = [];
   var element = '';

// Get table headers
   for(i = 1; i <= columns; i ++){
   element = metaData.getColumnLabel(i);
   value.push(element);
}
   values.push(value);

// Get table data row by row
   while(results.next()){
   value = [];
   for(i = 1; i <= columns; i ++){
    element = results.getString(i);
    value.push(element);
  }
  values.push(value);
}

// Cloese connection
   results.close();

// Write data to sheet Data
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
sheetData.getRange(2, 1, values.length, value.length).setValues(values);
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('The data has been updated.');
}catch(err){
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(err.message);
} 
}
```

Is it possible to select id, name and page from all three tables in one query and get the result in arrival order? I entered the same id in each table one by one, I mean, `1` in `table1`, `1` in `table2` and `1` in `table3` in that order, then I did the same with `2` and etc, this is how the output should look:

`id` `name` `page`

`1` `name1` `toys`

`1` `name2` `food`

`1` `name3` `electronics`

`2` `name4` `toys`

`2` `name5` `food`

`2` `name6` `electronics`

`3` `name7` `toys`

`3` `name8` `food`

`3` `name9` `electronics`

But in the output they get grouped by table, and that doesn't work me:

`id` `name` `page`

`1` `name1` `toys`

`2` `name4` `toys`

`3` `name7` `toys`

`1` `name2` `food`

`2` `name5` `food`

`3` `name8` `food`

`1` `name3` `electronics`

`2` `name6` `electronics`

`3` `name9` `electronics`

I would post a picture, but I do not have enough reputation.

I need the output in arrival order, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ORDER BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) clause:

```
var sql = '(SELECT id, name, page FROM table1) UNION (SELECT id, name, page FROM table2) UNION (SELECT id, name, page FROM table3) ORDER BY id';
```

Comment: that doesn't work for me either, because any of the tables can receive more entries than the other two. If the last row in the spreadsheet is from `table 2` with id = 10, and the next entry in `table 1` has an id = 4, it should still be after the row with id = 10 from `table 2` in the sheet.
I need them to be ordered in order of arrival regardless of any of the values in the tables.
Sorry for my bad english, i'm form Venezuela.

Comment: @Obed Is the arrival date time recorded in the database?

Comment: Yup, I just added an entry and this is the format: 2019-05-21 18:46:43.

Comment: Thanks you very much, I used the query that you described above with the `ORDER BY date` and it worked exactly as I wanted... in a way I feel stupid because I did not think to order it by date XD, thanks again bro.